# Is this a raise or a 3bet from bb?

Tags: pre-flop, betting-position, range

Let's assume situation like this:
6 seat table, preflop action, hero is CO, everyone folds or limps including hero who calls.
BB rises.

Should this be considered rise or 3bet from perspective of hero at CO?
Or maybe both depeneding on our application.

I am asking because to me that would be simple "raise" but in one preflop ranges guide I found there is no range for "co raised by bb" (as if this situation is not possible) but instead there is a range "co 3beted by bb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a raise by the Big Blind. A "limp" is really just a special case of a call of the original "1-bet" (i.e. the big blind itself).

Most pre-flop charts don't cater for the possibility of limpers. "Open-limping" - i.e. being the first person to limp - is almost universally considered poor play, so there are few if any pre-flop charts for this case.

(There are some situations where limping is more acceptable, for example as part of a more advanced Small Blind strategy, especially in tournaments or when playing "heads up" poker, but those scenarios require much more than a simple pre-flop chart to implement properly. It is also more acceptable to "over-limp" - i.e. limp behind another player who has already limped - than to open-limp.)

I think you will struggle to find any chart for "limped CO vs BB raise" because most people's advice to the CO in this case would simply be "raise or fold, don't limp".

The chart for "CO when 3-bet by BB" refers to the case where the CO has raised (not limped) and then the BB re-raises, i.e. 3-bets.

Comment: Oh yes, you are totally right! If I took a look at the chart for CO unopened, it says only raise or fold, therefore if these charts were followed, the situation I described will not happen. Thank you!